# JSONP compatibility

Tags: ajax, api, server, jsonp

Can JSONP be used with any API/server which returns JSON or does the server API have to be programmed/configured to return JSONP when the JSONP flag is inserted into a GET request.

If the server does need to be specifically configured to work with JSONP.

Is there any way to make a cross domain AJAX request from the client only?
ie
Without using any server side code
and without reprogramming or reconfiguring the API your requesting data from